# Have CakePHP saveAll function to ignore errors and continue

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Trying to make it simple, I have an excel spreadsheet of people and their emails. What I want is to use saveAll to insert them all at once in the database.

Problem is that I need to re-upload the spreadsheet everytime it has some new people in it. In that case, I need saveAll to save all the new people and ignore the validation errors that will happen due to the old people already existing in the database (people emails have unique rule). Any ideas?

**EDIT:** What I have now is that, when the saveAll method tries to save a record that already exists (i.e. whose email is already in the database) it doesn't save anything. What I need is to save the new ones that come from the spreadsheet, and ignore the ones that already exist (i.e. not save the ones that already exist).

Comment: any ideas regarding what? what is the problem? you are not ignoring the validation errors or you want to ignore them but you don't know how? or what?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize it was that unclear. Will update trying to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the second parameter to false so that validation is not checked.

Given your requirements, I would do this:

Loop through the data and check if that particular record exist, if it doesn't then push it to a temp array.

Now you can use that temp array as a parameter for your saveAll call.

The pseudo code would be something like this:

```
foreach ($originalDataToBeSaved as $something) {
    if ($this->find('count', array('conditions' => $yourConditions)) == 0) {
        $tempArray[] = $something;    
    }
}
$this->saveAll($tempArray);
```

**Edit:** I updated the code to reflect what Nunser said, new data doesn't have ID thus we need to do our search using another search criteria.

Comment: though, the new data will not have ids, so he'll have to compare by some other field (just to keep that in mind)

Comment: Then do a findByEmail or something?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach ($originalDataToBeSaved as $key => $something) {
    if ($this->hasAny($your_condition_to_chekc_existing_user) {
        unset($originalDataToBeSaved[$key]);    
    }
}
$this->saveAll(($originalDataToBeSaved);
```

if you dont want to validate then use -

```
$this->saveAll(($originalDataToBeSaved, array('validate' => false));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I ended up using a similar solution, with validateMany.